ML Model training - System Memory usage increasing over epoch
I am implementing a simple MLP using sagemaker particularly an aws ml.g4.xlarge machine and I noticed that ram memory keeps increasing over epoch. I am using pytorch.lightning for ML model architecture. I am using a dataloader with 64 workers.
ML Flow - System Metrics
What happens is that the model when reaches 70% of training crashes the machine saying it memory max limit is reached. As you can see between batches the memory is increasing - my understanding is that between batches each batch is used and then removed out of memory so that only thing that changes between batches is the weight updates. So the memory usage should not increase over steps.
I tried removing logs, nothing changed. Though that might be the number of workers, added just one worker and the memory usage kept increasing over time. However with num_workers=0 it stabilizes and does not increase over time - but the training takes significant amount of time
ML Flow - System Metrics - num_workers=0
How can I fix this issue?

Hey. Your question will likely be closed. Please structure your request so that it follows our community rules.

why is my question not following community rules?

Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to understand how to ask a question. Stack overflow is strictly for asking and answering programming question. You question is asking for recommendation and asks multiple questions. Edit your question according to community guidelines to avoid getting closed.

Edited the question, by asking a simple question and not multiple. With all due respect @DrinkandDerive I think that this question is relevant for ML and should not be closed, it has a clear question and prints described the issues.

This is a known issue caused by how python shares objects in multiprocessing. You can read more here

I think that you somewhere did not delete lists, numpy arrays. Because I have similar problem, and it was caused by usual list that I forgot to make empty after each iteration

Thank you @Nikolai! For some reason you also got -1 score, which is sad... your suggestion was really good. https://github.com/fuzihaofzh/cstl this package allows to convert into deletable format, they explain here the cause of this issue and how to solve

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/13246 here they describe the issue at fullest

so instead of deleting the lists you can just convert them with cstl
